# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk after build my Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

**Hi i have a problem with loading chunk whehn i build my project and run it on browser i get this error in my browser console:**

```
"Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk app-modules-auth-auth-module failed.
```

[image: this is complete error report in my web console]

**What should i do to solve this problem ?**
**nothing works in my angular app because of this problem**

> NOTE: after i build my angular project i move js file to a directory
>   such this:
>
> ```
> project/public/assets/admin
> ```
>
> and index html file to this directory:
>
> ```
> project/public/views
> ```
>
> and my angular files are in this directory:
>
> ```
> project/project-front/src
> ```

[image: Package.json file if you need it!]

Comment: Can you add code here?

Comment: How are you building the project? Do you see this error when you simply run? Or only after you try to deploy?

Comment: show ur package json file

Comment: @DeborahK
I get this error after i build my project when my angular app is in serve mode it works with no error

Comment: @DharmarajKavatagi
Which part of my codes i must to add here?

Comment: @AAshishjha
I added a screen shot at the end of my question that contains my project's package.json file

Comment: You are using Angular v5, but the v6 version of the Angular CLI. That could cause an issue?

Comment: @p.daniel it may be ur dependency error try angularfire2: 5.0.0-rc.3 and promise-polyfill: ^6.02 and firebase: 4.6.0